# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parser configuration problem:

Tags: xml-parsing, xslt, saxon

I am stuck with this error

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parser configuration problem: namespace reporting is not enabled
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.getNameCode(ReceivingContentHandler.java:383)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.startElement(ReceivingContentHandler.java:289)

while running the following code

**xmlHandler.startElement("D:\XmlFiles\XmlFromRhapsody.xml", "", qName, atts);**

xmlHandler is --> TransformerHandler xmlHandler;

I am not sure of enabling namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by supplying the localname when calling the startElement method. This means that you to make the same calls to the ContentHandler that a namespace-aware XML parser would make.

So, you have ..

```
xmlHandler.startElement("D:\XmlFiles\XmlFromRhapsody.xml", "", qName, atts);
```

You need to add the local name as the 2nd parameter instead of leaving it blank.

Also, If you don't want to make these changes you can use saxon-8.9.0.4.jar which should work without any errors.